# On running the emulator getting this error: Cause: invalid type code: 1D

Tags: android-studio-4.0

Recently i installed android studio, and when i run the app for the first time it ran without any error but now, when i run it, it has given the error i.e.

```
Cause: invalid type code: 1D
```

and

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/dell/AndroidStudioProjects/disha





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 95ms
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this error please make the changes below:

****Install Java SDK version**:** 14 or above.

****JDK Download link**:** https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html

And in `gradle-wrapper.properties` please use grade **version 6.3** or above.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helps.